# Heroku Logs: FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM We're sorry, but something went wrong. App works fine in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

My app works fine in development but for some reason I am getting the "We're sorry, but something went wrong" error when it runs in production. And it is only when I run this specific page. Please help me understand why the server is shutting down.

```html
2015-09-12T13:22:04.223590+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/findparking?lat=44.6684713&lng=-63.491052100000005&name=My%20Location&rad=0.5" host=www.ugopark.com request_id=f91f3e17-92d5-4a76-b4c9-f1417e4b095e fwd="100.42.240.204" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=31ms status=500 bytes=1754
2015-09-12T13:23:27.202566+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/findparking?lat=44.6684713&lng=-63.491052100000005&name=My%20Location&rad=0.5" host=www.ugopark.com request_id=8b4aa884-2914-4ea2-a926-f099da0acdef fwd="100.42.240.204" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30ms status=500 bytes=1754
2015-09-12T13:24:06.808472+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2015-09-12T13:24:09.002852+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2015-09-12T13:24:09.540522+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-09-12 13:24:09] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
2015-09-12T13:24:09.540529+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `select'
2015-09-12T13:24:09.540531+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in start'
2015-09-12T13:24:09.540532+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
2015-09-12T13:24:09.540533+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start'
2015-09-12T13:24:09.540535+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:34:in `run'
2015-09-12T13:24:09.540536+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:286:in `start'
2015-09-12T13:24:09.540537+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
2015-09-12T13:24:09.540539+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
2015-09-12T13:24:09.540540+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2015-09-12T13:24:09.540541+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
2015-09-12T13:24:09.540544+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2015-09-12T13:24:09.540543+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2015-09-12T13:24:09.540545+00:00 app[web.1]:  bin/rails:8:in `require'
2015-09-12T13:24:09.540547+00:00 app[web.1]:  bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
2015-09-12T13:24:09.540553+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-09-12 13:24:09] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2015-09-12T13:24:09.540573+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-09-12 13:24:09] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2015-09-12T13:24:09.574346+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2015-09-12T13:24:09.574352+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.2.1 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:59176
2015-09-12T13:24:09.574353+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2015-09-12T13:24:09.574354+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2015-09-12T13:24:09.574356+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2015-09-12T13:24:10.404692+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2015-09-12T13:24:14.787364+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 37527 -e production`
2015-09-12T13:24:23.123953+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-09-12 13:24:23] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2015-09-12T13:24:23.124568+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-09-12 13:24:23] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=3 port=37527
2015-09-12T13:24:23.124110+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-09-12 13:24:23] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2015-04-13) [x86_64-linux]
```

Comment: "it is only when I run this specific page" and what's on that page that's not on other pages?

Answer (score 1):

The exception you're getting here has no relation with the 500s you were getting just before.
The reason you're not seeing any stacktrace for those exceptions is because your app is currently logging to a local file (which is the default with rails) when it should send it's logs to STDOUT so the heroku logger can catch them and show them to you.

You can install the [rails_12factor](https://github.com/heroku/rails_12factor) gem, which will configure your app to send logs to STDOUT. Once this is done and your app is redeployed, you should be able to see the exact exception being raised when calling that page.